# c# - как получить ссылку объекта

Tags: c#, .net

Здравствуйте. Если есть 2 класса `class A` и `class B:A{}` и создать объект класса B, но ссылку дать на A, т.е `A obj = new B()` писав `obj.GetType()` можно получить тип объекта. А есть ли такая функция чтобы вернула не тип объекта, а ссылку, т.е A ?

Comment: "не тип объекта, а ссылку" - ?? `typeof(A)`

Comment: Класс на которую ссылается объект

Comment: на объект может ссылаться сто переменных разных типов - от `В` до `System.Object`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то автор хочет узнавать тот тип, с которым объявлена переменная.
Оператор `typeof()`, к сожалению работает только с идентификаторами типов. К переменным он неприменим.
Однако, можно извратиться, создав обобщённую (generic) функцию для вызова с автоматическим выводом generic-аргумента.
Вот пример:

```
using System;

class Solution
{
    static Type VariableType<T>(ref T var_value)
    {
        return typeof(T);
    }

    class A { }
    class B : A { }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A obj_A = new A();
        B obj_B = new B();
        A obj_X = new B();

        Console.WriteLine("VariableType(obj_A) = {0}", VariableType(ref obj_A).Name);
        Console.WriteLine("VariableType(obj_B) = {0}", VariableType(ref obj_B).Name);
        Console.WriteLine("VariableType(obj_X) = {0}", VariableType(ref obj_X).Name);
    }
}
```

Выводом будет:
VariableType(obj_A) = A
VariableType(obj_B) = B
VariableType(obj_X) = A

P.S.:
Ключевое слово `ref` в объявлении функции использовать необязательно.
Я это сделал только для того, чтобы нельзя было подсунуть выражение вместо переменной.

Comment: Благодарен Вам !